# Verify numerically relation between mean deviation and standard deviation

Tags: programming, variance, standard-deviation, mean, normal

I was reading "We Don’t Quite Know What We Are Talking About When We Talk About Volatility" by Goldstein and Taleb, and I was trying to quickly verify numerically the relation between mean deviation and standard deviation.

However, I get that 0.8 is the ratio between **mean deviation and variance**, not **mean deviation and standard deviation**. See code example below.

Can anybody explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np

n = 10000
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[n, 1])
sum(abs(x)) / sum(x ** 2)  # approx 0.8
sum(abs(x)) / sum(x ** 2) ** 0.5  # approx 80
```

[image]

Comment: You calculate sums, not averages, hence the error. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation

Answer (score 2):

There's a small typo,

Mean absolute deviation, with 0 mean = sum(abs(x))/n

Standard deviation, with 0 mean = np.sqrt(sum(x ** 2))/np.sqrt(n)

So when you divide MAD over SD you should use:

sum(abs(x)) / (np.sqrt(n) * np.sqrt(sum(x ** 2)))

which gives 0.8 as expected